# Rails: Id validation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller

I want to create a validation to my database. I have a table Animals with 3 column: Cat, Dog, Fish. All column are nil by default. 
So, when a new row is created, I need to have an id just to ONE column, other MUST be nil. For Example:

```
Dog: nil | Cat: 5 | Fish: nil | IS OKAY
Dog: 8 | Cat: nil | Fish: nil | IS OKAY
Dog: nil | Cat: 3 | Fish: 4 | WRONG, IMPOSSIBLE TO SAVE
Dog: 1 | Cat: nil | Fish: 9 | WRONG, IMPOSSIBLE TO SAVE
```

What I have to do to validate this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  validate :only_one_column_must_be_set

  def only_one_column_must_be_set
    if [dog, cat, fish].compact.count > 1
      errors.add(:base, "only one value must be set")
    end
  end
end
```

Check [compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) to exclude nil values from the array.